# while loop inside for loop, confused?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, abstract-data-type

Completely new to programming, and I was doing a project and I am confused on how I can make it work. Please help me

```
        boolean answer1 = true; 
        for (int i=0;i<q.questionbank.length;++i)
       {   q.Question = input(q.questionbank[i]);

        while(answer1 == true)
       {

        if (q.Question.equals(a.correctans) || (q.Question.equals(a.impossibleans) || (q.Question.equals(a.wrongans))))
        {
            score = printquiz(answer,score,q.Question);
            answer1 = false;
        }
        else
        {
            print("Not a Valid Answer, please try again\n");
        }
    }
    }
    return score;
```

Over here, I have a class called questionbank and quiz. The correctans/impossibleans/wrongans are part of the quiz data type. whereas the q.question is part of questionbank. I have some question on an array in the questionbank data type. I want to use for loop to go through the questions and if the user input the correct answer, there score goes up. It works for the first question but doesnt for the second question. usually when they answer correctly, I have another method printquiz that has decision statements to tell the user if their answer is correct or wrong, and assign them points. but its not even going to that method after the first iteration of the loop. I am confused on what is going on. Please help me

Comment: I'd guess you need to initialize `answer1` inside the `for` loop, but before the `while` loop.

Comment: @FredLarson OMG that worked. Wtf I spent 1 hour trying out different thing before posting here. I can't believe one simple thing fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would have set it up.  Assume the answer to be false until you get one.  Then set it to true to exit the loop.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < q.questionbank.length; ++i) {
        q.Question = input(q.questionbank[i]);

        answer1 = false;
        while (!answer1) {

            if (q.Question.equals(a.correctans) || (q.Question.equals(a.impossibleans) || (q.Question.equals(a.wrongans)))) {
                score = printquiz(answer, score, q.Question);
                answer1 = true;
            } else {
                print("Not a Valid Answer, please try again\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Apparently putting the boolean answer1 inside the for loop fixes it. I dont know why, but that works. I literally spent an hour trying to figure this out. I cant believe putting it inside works

Comment: It has to be inside the for loop because the while loop expects it to be initialized at the beginning of the while loop.  During the while loop, it eventually gets set (in your original question) to false.  And then it would stay false until the for loop is exited - unless it is reset to the initial value.

Comment: yeah. I get it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The second time doesn't work, because you set `answer1` to `false` and never set it back to `true` again. So the `while` loop is not being entered anymore (= doesn't evaluate to true anymore) after the `answer1 = false` line of code in the if statement has been reached the first time.

To fix this, try to put `answer1 = true` inside the for loop, before the while loop.

Comment: yep you're right. I am an idiot. Thanks for the answer though. I was about to go mad here